# How to properly handle a nil UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

When the `viewDidLoad` is called the view is supposed to be loaded.

But I always crash in `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow` being nil...

Where should I put my code to have it called once the view is loaded and not everytime the user comes back (I have excluded viewWillAppear for that reason) ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Situation 1:** - Manual `UIWindow` creation in App's delegate

You have probably somehow added a `UIViewController` to a `UIWindow` before setting it as key.

You should call `window.makeKeyAndVisible()` in your app's delegate after creating the window.

**Situation 2:** - Automatic storyboard instantiation

The system reads your storyboard, initializes the root view controller, prepares it by calling `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`, adds it to the window and shows the window.

What happens is the system cannot just set the window to the front and animate the view controller onto it, because it's the first view controller and you are not push/popping of a nav controller. And `viewDidLoad` can take some time... So the `Default.png` is showing in the meanwhile until the view controller is ready.

Then it calls `viewDidAppear`, when it has actually appeared. So that's where you *should* be able to access a `keyWindow`

**Situation 3:**

You are in a weird situation where you have windows but none of them is the "key" window currently, but you desperately need to access the window.

Call `UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows`, see if it's not empty and take the first element. `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window` might have a value too, but it's usually only when the window is *key* already.

Comment: I am using Storyboard (from Apple's boilerplate), I don't manually instantiate my `UIViewController`.

Comment: I've updated the answer to be more complete, and account for your situation too

Comment: Thanks for the workflow, so I would have somehow to put my code in viewWillAppear and manually check that this has been called for the first time ?

Comment: Yes. If it is needed to run only once - then you could have a boolean flag "isAppearingForTheFirstTime"...

Comment: Making the call in `viewDidAppear` (as opposed to `viewWillAppear`) fixed a similar issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `window` property of the application delegate:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get nil from "UIApplication.shared.keyWindow" at "viewDidLoad", Try wrap your code inside of DispatchQueue.

ex)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if var window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```