# Getting keyWindow nil inside Framework

Tags: ios, swift, keywindow

I am making a framework where I need to get `keyWindow` inside framework to add some view on it.When trying to get by usual way `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow` then every time it is returning `nil`.

Is it possible to get `keywindow` inside framework ? If yes then how to get it or is there any other way to add some view on top of others view irrespective of any viewcontrollers.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324660/how-to-properly-handle-a-nil-uiapplication-sharedapplication-keywindow

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I seen the answer but nothing is working

Comment: try this  `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I tried as `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!!.addSubview(someview)` but nothing is appearing

Comment: @SunilSharma Did you find any solution for this question?